# React routes nesting on homepage

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am able to get routes working on pages level, also nested routes working fine if not on the homepage.
e.g

```
/ ........ homepage
/pageA ... PageA
   /pageA1.....PageA1 (nested)
   /PageA2.....PageA2 (nested)
/PageB ... PageB
```

However, I am unable to have nested routes on homepage, the strucutre looks like below

```
/..........PageA(homepage)
   /pageA1.....PageA1 (nested)
   /PageA2.....PageA2 (nested)
/PageB ... PageB
```

Here is the code, the code can be played on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-thunder-sw5xd)

```
    const PageB1 = () => <>"Page B 1"</>;
    const PageB2 = () => <>"Page B 2"</>;
    const PageB3 = () => <>"Page B 3"</>;

    const PageA = ({ match }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/pagea1">Page A 1</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/pagea2">Page A 2</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/pagea3">Page A 3</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <hr />
          <Route exact path={match.path + "/pagea1"} component={PageB1} />
          <Route exact path={match.path + "/pagea2"} component={PageB2} />
          <Route exact path={match.path + "/pagea3"} component={PageB3} />
        </>
      );
    };
    const PageB = () => " Page A";

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Page A</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/pageb">Page B</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <hr />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={PageA} />
                <Route path="/pageb" component={PageB} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

This code is working fine for pageA(*homepage*) and pageB, but nested page `Page A 1`, `Page A 2`, `Page A 3` are not working

If I remove `exact` from line 45 change it to `<Route path="/" component={PageA} />` 
and remove `match.path +` from line 22-24 change the code to

```
<Route exact path={"/pagea1"} component={PageB1} />
<Route exact path={"/pagea2"} component={PageB2} />
<Route exact path={"/pagea3"} component={PageB3} />
```

Then the nested pages will work fine. But in the meantime, it breaks PageA(homepage), PageB.
Could someone please to advise where is the error I made? Thanks

Comment: because match.path contain value '/' and you are adding that value to the nested route path i.e. path "//pagea1" so it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the props path which you are passing to A component have value "/", and you are adding that value in the nested Route path i.e. //pagea1. so this is the reason it is not working.

one more thing i observed over here it is always suggested to add generic route in the last and here in your code you are add generic "/" route first.

follow the below code :-

```
 const PageB1 = () => <>"Page B 1"</>;
 const PageB2 = () => <>"Page B 2"</>;
 const PageB3 = () => <>"Page B 3"</>;
 const PageA = ({ match }) => {
 return (
   <>
    <ul>
     <li>
       <Link to="/pagea1">Page A 1</Link>
     </li>
     <li>
       <Link to="/pagea2">Page A 2</Link>
     </li>
     <li>
       <Link to="/pagea3">Page A 3</Link>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <hr />
     /* match.path  have  "/" so you can remove it here 
      * because you are adding / in pagea1 */ 
   <Route exact path={ "/pagea1"} component={PageB1} /> 
     
   /* this syntax will work too because i have omit / from pageea2 value */
   <Route exact path={match.path + "pagea2"} component={PageB2} /> 
   <Route exact path={match.path + "pagea3"} component={PageB3} />
 </>
 );
};

const PageB = () => " Page A";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Router>
      <div>
       <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Page A</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/pageb">Page B</Link>
        </li>
       </ul>
       <hr />
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/pageb" component={PageB} /> // keep specific paths 
                                                    //route on top to generic 
                                                      one 
         <Route path="/" component={PageA} /> // and in case of generic 
                                                    you don't need exact 
       </Switch>
     </div>
   </Router>
 </div>
);}
```

Hope it will work .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I ticked this one as I tried `redirect` before I asked the question, redirect worked fine. personally prefer a way to without a `redirect` soluton.

Answer (score 2):

In this [You code](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-thunder-sw5xd)

***exact*** keyword only render pagea for ***/*** url

when we click pagea1, now the url is ***/pagea1***

so we don't see either pagea nor pageb

when you removed ***exact*** now every url start with ***/*** render ***pagea***, in this case ***pageb*** won't work and ***/pagea1*** url also stop works, because you are mentioning

```
path={match.path + "/pagea1"}
```

where math.path is ***/*** so ***//pagea1*** will render pagea1.

Instead of removing ***exact*** and ***math.path*** you can create ***/pagea*** and redirect ***/*** to ***/pagea***

**Note:** you have to make significant changes in **PageA** links

After that code will look like this

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const PageB1 = () => <>"Page B 1"</>;
const PageB2 = () => <>"Page B 2"</>;
const PageB3 = () => <>"Page B 3"</>;

const PageA = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/pagea/pagea1">Page A 1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/pagea/pagea2">Page A 2</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/pagea/pagea3">Page A 3</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr />
      <Route exact path={match.path + "/pagea1"} component={PageB1} />
      <Route exact path={match.path + "/pagea2"} component={PageB2} />
      <Route exact path={match.path + "/pagea3"} component={PageB3} />
    </>
  );
};
const PageB = () => " Page B";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Page A</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/pageb">Page B</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <hr />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/pagea" component={PageA} />
            <Route path="/pageb" component={PageB} />
            <Redirect to="/pagea" />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**PS:** Hope I answered your question, if not let me know.